# Finding a certain rotation matrix

Tags: rotations

How do you find the set of n by n rotation matrices that when multiplied, rotate an n-dimensional point(a[1],a[2],a[3]...a[n]) around the center point (0,0...0) such that you get the point (b,b,...b) where b is a real number?

Comment: I don't think that has a unique answer in more than three dimensions.

Comment: Any answer would be helpful, i dont need all the solutions.

Comment: Can we assume that the point $a$ is on the same $n$-sphere as the point $b$, i.e. that lengths are preserved?

Comment: To RobertTheTutor: Yes, lenghts are preserved.

Comment: What is the definition you take of a rotation in dimension $n$ ?  Is it connected to an orthogonal matrix with determinant 1 ?

Comment: A rotation on a point P gives a point R such that sqrt((R[1])^2+(R[2])^2+...(R[n])^2) = sqrt((P[1])^2+(P[2])^2+...(P[n])^2). I hope that answers your question because honestly i didnt understand your question even though i know what an orthogonal matrix and a determinant is.

Comment: 1) I wasn't aware of your anwer because you haven't prefixed it by '@JeanMarie' 2) As I understand, any orthogonal matrix will do : see my answer using Householder symmetry operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is simple way to achieve it.

We want vector $U=(a_1,a_2, \cdots a_n)^T$ to be mapped onto vector $V=(1,1, \cdots 1)^T$ by a certain matrix (we assume, as you do, that $U$ and $V$ have the same norm ; the $T$s are there for considering them as *column* vectors).

Let $D=U-V$ and $N=D/\|D\|$ its normalized version (therefore $N^TN=1$, a property that will be sueful later).

Then consider the so-called [**Householder operator**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation):

$$H_N:=I_n-2NN^T $$

It has the property :

$$H_N^2=H_NH_N=(I_n-2NN^T )(I_n-2NN^T )=I_n-4NN^T+4N\underbrace{N^TN}_{1}N^T=I_n$$

proving that it is symmetry, in fact a symmetry with respect to the hyperplane with normal vector $N$.

Therefore $$H_NU=V$$

(this can be established by computation also)

Comment: Thank you for your time. Even though I will need to research a little bit to understand your answer, it seems on a first read that I will solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

To find a matrix, we have two vectors, the starting point and the ending point.

First transform to an orthonormal coordinate system (using Gram-Schmidt) where the starting point is the first vector (normalized) and the first two basis vectors have the same span as the starting and ending point vectors.  Then perform a 2D rotation.  Then transform back.